# Mapping view not updating on tab navigator in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have 4 tabs load using tabnavigator. I have home, favourite, cart and profile screen. User will choose desired product on home, add it to cart. The badge count on tab is updating, but when I'm go to cart screen, it is still plain empty.

I'm running on development. So if I refresh my script on VSCode, the product will be show on cart screen.

This is my cart script:-

```
renderProductList() {
  var contents = appGlobal.ObjProduct.map((item) => {
    return (
      <Content key={item.ProdID}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
          console.log('Touch item: ' + JSON.stringify(item));
        }}>
          <Card>
            <CardItem>
              <Left>
                <FastImage
                  source={{ uri: item.ProdImage, priority: FastImage.priority.normal, }}
                  style={{
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                  }}
                  resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover}
                />
              </Left>
              <Body>
                <Text>{item.ProdName}</Text>
              </Body>
              <Right>

              </Right>
            </CardItem>
          </Card>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Content>
    );
  });
  return (
    <Content padder>
      {contents}
    </Content>
  )
}
renderNoProduct() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', }}>
      <SvgUri width="150" height="150" source={EmptyCart} />
      <Text style={{ color: 'gray', marginTop: 10 }}>Your cart is empty :(</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
render() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Header searchBar rounded>
        <Left style={{ flex: null }}>
        </Left>
        <Body style={{ flex: 3 }}>
          <Title style={{ marginLeft: 10, }}>Shopping Cart</Title>
        </Body>
        <Right style={{ flex: null }}>
        </Right>
      </Header>
      {appGlobal.ObjProduct.length > 0 ? this.renderProductList() : this.renderNoProduct()}
      <Footer>
        <FooterTab>
          <Button style={{ backgroundColor: '#d15f02' }}>
            <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Proceed to order</Text>
          </Button>
        </FooterTab>
      </Footer>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

It is another way to make it global mapping or product change when using tab navigator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call a function when the focused screen changes on TabNavigation

on your Cart tab use this:

```
import { withNavigationFocus } from 'react-navigation';

class CartScreen extends React.Component {

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (prevProps.isFocused !== this.props.isFocused) {
             // Call any action to update you view
             //fetch data when the component is focused
             //To prevent extra component re-renders, you may need to write some logic in shouldComponentUpdate
            }
          }

    render() {
      return (
         <Container>
              <Text>{this.props.isFocused ? 'Focused' : 'Not focused'}</Text>
          </Container>
        );
     }
   }

  // withNavigationFocus returns a component that wraps CartScreen and passes
  // in the navigation prop

export default withNavigationFocus(CartScreen);
```

> withNavigationFocus

**withNavigationFocus** is a higher-order component which passes the isFocused prop into a wrapped component. It's useful if you need to use the focus state in the render function of your screen component or another component rendered somewhere inside of a screen.