# TabIcon count not updated if record is deleted on tab focus in react-native CLI

Tags: react-native

Regarding my question from [SO: Mapping view not updating on tab navigator in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59679491/3436326), I have added function to delete the product from cart. And yes the cart view is reducing after deleting, but the tabicon badge count is still on last count, until I press on any tab other than cart.

For adding product cart to object, yes it will update the count accordingly. Just when delete record from object, the count is not updated.

[image]

My script on cart screen has follow suggestion from linked posting:-

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.isFocused !== this.props.isFocused) {
    this.setState({ prodData: appGlobal.ObjProduct });
  }
}
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  if (this.props.prodData !== nextState.prodData) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

On TabHelpers class:-

```
const tabScreen = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        'Home': {
            screen: homeStack,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                    <Icon name='home' size={20} color={tintColor} />
                ),
            },
        },
        'Favourite': {
            screen: favStack,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                    <Icon name='heart' size={20} color={tintColor} />
                ),
            },
        },
        'Cart': {
            screen: cartStack,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                    <View>
                        <Icon name='shopping-cart' size={20} color={tintColor} />
                        {typeof appGlobal.ObjProduct !== 'undefined' && appGlobal.ObjProduct.length > 0 ?
                            <Badge style={{ position: 'absolute', right: 10, top: 0, height: 13 }}>
                                <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 8 }}>{appGlobal.ObjProduct.length}</Text>
                            </Badge>
                            : null}
                    </View>
                ),
            },
        },
        'Profile': {
            screen: profileStack,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                    <Icon name='user' size={20} color={tintColor} />
                ),
            },
        }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Home',
        headerMode: 'none',
        lazy: false,
        backBehavior: 'initialRoute',
        swipeEnabled: true,
        animationEnabled: true,
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        tabBarOptions: {
            showLabel: true,
            showIcon: true,
            activeTintColor: '#ffffff',
            activeBackgroundColor: '#4961c4',
            inactiveTintColor: '#4962a6',
            style: {
                backgroundColor: '#475691',
            },
            labelStyle: {
                textAlign: 'center',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
            },
            indicatorStyle: {
                borderBottomColor: '#FFFFFF',
                borderBottomWidth: 2,
            },
        },
        defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation, defaultHandler }) => {
                navigation.popToTop();
                defaultHandler();
            },
        }),
    }
);

export default createAppContainer(tabScreen);
```

Did I miss something or wrongly apply?